# RelativeLayout. 2 views. Один из view расположен строго над вторым

Tags: xml, android, view

Есть view v1 и v2. v1 определённым образом задан в layout xml, но при этом в определённое время программно я могу менять его `LayoutParams`: отступы или размеры.

Можно ли обойтись только средствами xml, чтобы view v1 всегда был над v2? Т.е. чтобы не приходилось как для v1 также задавать отступы и размеры?

Под "над" я подразумевал, что он будет поверх и полностью повторять отступы и размеры v2

Answer (score 1):

Используйте android:layout_above или android:layout_below

Comment: Добавил в первом посте предложение

Answer (score 0):

в xml сначала определи v2, а потом v1.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <View 
     android:id = "@+id/view2">
   </View>
   <View
     android:id = "@+id/view1">
   </View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Добавил в первом посте предложение